# Spring-boot loading resource file . Working eclipse but not when deployed in server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Below is the my code to load the resource file and assigning the resource to file object.**

```
   @Value("classpath:responsexml/TestLoadResponse.xml") /* Used value attribute for loading the file from the specified path */
    File testLoadResponse ;  /* Assigning the variable */
```

The above is working fine in eclipse but when deployed spring boot application jar ,I am facing the below error

```
 **exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.io.File'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not retrieve file for class path resource**
```

Comment: Can you paste the @Value binding variable ?

Comment: How do you create the application jar? If you are using Maven/Gradle, check that folders marked as source in Eclipse match those used by these tools (usually `src/main/(java|resources)` )

Comment: You cannot access contents of an archive (such as `*.jar` or `*.war`) via `io.File` abstraction. They are not (directly) accessible on the filesystem. Think of it as a ZIP. You can however access those resources via `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`. Furthermore, spring provides the `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource` abstraction for that job. If you wonder why it works inside the IDE: the project-layout is exploded - and therefore the resources are available on the filesystem.

Comment: Thank you all for your response . I have used the maven tool to generate the spring-boot application jar . But I could see success result by using below changes .  @Value("${home.path}/conf/TestLoadResponse.xml")
 File testResponse ;
 Where home.path is my application install path .

Comment: Inject a spring `Resource` instead and use its methods to get at the data within.